# Clojure & ClojureScript REPL (emacs + cider + boot)

Tags: emacs, clojure, clojurescript, cider

The boot task [boot-cljs-repl](https://github.com/adzerk-oss/boot-cljs-repl) provides a way to connect to a ClojureScript REPL which interacts with a running browser instance.

If properly added to the build.boot dependencies one can call the function `(start-repl)` from within a Clojure repl in order to start up a ClojureScript REPL.

I'm connecting to the clojure REPL from withing Emacs, by the help of the [cider](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider) package with the function: `(cider-connect)`

I'm trying to figure out how to have a Clojure REPL and a ClojureScript REPL in two different Emacs buffers (at the same time). The procedure described above does 'replace' the later by the former.

Calling `(cider-connect)` again, tells me that there is already another REPL running.

I think the behavior I'm looking for was the default when using leiningen + cider-jack-in / cider-jack-in-clojurescript. Those calls seem to be only meant for leiningen.

So, I'm asking: What's the *boot* way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `cider-connect` again you should see a prompt:

```
REPL buffer already exists (*cider-repl localhost*).  Do you really want to create a new one? (y or n)
```

Just hit `y` and you get a new REPL buffer.

Same for `cider-jack-in` and `cider-jack-in-clojurescript`.

Comment: alright, perfect. I thought this will replace the other. thx. Do you maybe know if cider-jack-in is just for leiningen or also works with boot?